# Django admin site not loading CSS

Tags: python, django

Not sure what is going on, but my admin page on my Django site isn't loading any CSS. Not sure if it has to do with `python manage.py collectstatic` but ever since I served my static files using this, my admin page doesn't load with CSS and instead, it's plain HTML. This same issue is happening with a few projects of mine when using `collectstatic`. Any ideas? They'd be appreciated. Since I don't know what the issue is or where to start, I'm not sure what code to provide. If you want to see anything, let me know.

I've noticed when I viewed the source of the admin page and clicked on the css links (`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css">`), the base.css file seems to be corrupted maybe ? [What the base.css looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/youTA.png) All the other css files when clicked are readable. [What the other css files look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQZiI.png)

Comment: Are you running the project with `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: @PedramParsian Yes

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APP` section in your settings file?

Comment: @F.Serna Yea I have that too

Comment: do you have ```STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')``` in your settings.py?

Comment: @ha-neul Yes. All my static roots, urls as well as media are correct

Comment: so, under the Static-root folder, do you see ```admin``` folder with ```css``` subfolder? also, when you run collectstatic, was there any error message?

Comment: @ha-neul Yes I've checked both. No errors and the admin folder has a populated css folder. Another weird thing I noticed is that my site changes up depending on if I'm using ```localhost:8000``` or ```127.0.0.1:8000```. Like somethings won't render with ```127.0.0.1``` like they do with ```localhost```. Not sure if it has to do with ```collectstatic``` though.

Comment: I had a couple of times with css not doing its job; I solved it by deleting browser history. maybe worth a try.

Comment: @ha-neul Crazy how that worked lol. Fixed everything. Thank you

Comment: It didn't fix it for me, and I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the settings.py file

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

After that add the following in the URL:

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```